# nginx -AWS EC2 -Angular Subpath not working on direct request

Tags: angular, nginx, angular5

I have hosted my angular project on AWS ec2 instance.
Instance is successfully made and site is properly working.

When is make request
www.abc.com it works but when i make request for www.abc.com/login
it returns nginx error

404 Not found

**app.routing.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule',
     canActivate: [AuthGuard]
},
{ path: 'signup', loadChildren: './signup/signup.module#SignupModule' },
{ path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule' },
{ path: 'not-found', loadChildren: './not-found/not-found.module#NotFoundModule' },
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' },
```

];

**Server configuration nginx (sites-enabled)**

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/myfolder;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Is this angular code issue or server configuration issue??
How to solve this?

Comment: I think server name can be issue here in nginx. Please try with domain name instead of _
**server_name www.abc.com**

Comment: still same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I had to change =404 with index.html

Correct config is

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/myfolder;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name www.abc.com;

        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
```